# How are you supposed to buy epoxy?

Tags: epoxy

I have a project where we would want to do a flooring with epoxy for a water closet downstairs (because screw doing ceramic tiles) but really, buying epoxy resin seems a pretty hard thing to do.

The retailers here in Quebec dont seem to simply carry it (Home Depot, Rona, etc.) And it seem my only choice for buying it is speciality websites that would I guess send it by delivery and it does feel weird to receive chemicals by mail.

So is there a hurdle I'm not seeing? Do you absolutely have to go with experts to make epoxy for flooring?

How am I supposed to buy Epoxy? And more specifically flooring epoxy for a water closet?

Comment: There is nothing odd about delivering "chemicals" in a truck to your home.   If you don't have them delivered, they'll be delivered in a truck to the store and then in your car.  If your local shops don't carry what you want, I don't see what choice you have.     For a small WC why not just use vinyl?  It's so easy and cheap ... vinyl planks or a one-piece sheet to cover the whole room.  It will look and feel as good or better than epoxy.

Comment: You're probably shopping the wrong stores, since most use of epoxy flooring (particularly epoxy with broadcast color-chip type flooring) is industrial/commercial, not home-center customers.

Comment: Have you tried marine supply places?

Comment: While not an off-topic "product recommendation" question, this is an equally off-topic, "vendor recommendation" question. You buy the product wherever it's sold. If you're not comfortable buying it there, you either find another vendor or you don't buy it. If it were illegal to ship the "chemicals" you're interested in buying, then it wouldn't be sold by vendors who ship it. eg: Stand alone Li-Ion batteries cannot be air freighted. So they're sent by ground transport only. Doesn't mean you can't buy replacement Li-Ion batteries online.

Comment: do you have amazon where you live? they have tons of it.

Answer (score 1):

I recently saw large containers of it while browsing at DeSerres (the arts & craft store). I have no idea if the pricing is reasonable but you can walk out of there with several gallons.

Answer (score 1):

If there are any marinas or supply houses for boats that sell what is needed to outfit a boat, they will have the resin and fiberglass cloth if you need it.
I have seen gallon kits on the shelf of the West Marine I visited, but I only needed a quart kit.  ( Disclaimer: No I am not affiliated with West Marine. They happen have what I needed at the time)

Comment: Better to look for small family owned chandleries other than West Marine. West Marine has the popular stuff but they're overpriced (except on certain select loss-leaders in the flyer)... in other words, the Home Depot of marine LOL. The dominant brand of marine epoxies is  **West *System*** (totally unrelated to West Marine, and sanely priced as a rule).